# cmake and Installing opencv 4.x on Linux Debian 10 with Kernel 4.19.x

Tags: make, python3, cmake, opencv, cpp

I am finding this info. online for building OpenCV 4.x on their homepage. I have not found a way to compile the samples or examples. Is it possible with cmake to install examples from the OpenCV 4.x build process?

https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html is the link I followed to install with cmake and make, and sudo make install. I got the `cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..` down pat but I am trying to configure the examples/samples.

I have not been able to compile these examples or samples from the /build dir.

I also tried to install and compile the Python3 libraries but the compilation only allows for Python2. Are any other people having this issue and could you please provide some feedback?

Answer (score 0):

On the opencv.com website, https://opencv.org/releases/, go to the .zip file you want to install.

Copy the hyperlink of the file you want in .zip format, use `wget` with the .zip file to install it on your Linux SBC, and then use these below commands I got from a book called, "BeagleBone By Example, (Prabakar)."

command one: `wget https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/4.3.0.zip`

Or...

command two: `git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git`

Or...you can use git clone to get the release build of your choice on their github page online at https://github.com/opencv/opencv.

Once you install zip on your system, with a Debian server like I am using as a Distro, w/ `sudo apt install zip`, use the `unzip` command to "unzip" the .zip file.

Then, create a build directory after you get into your file that has been unzipped.

So,

```
/home/debian/
    |
    - wget opencv.zip -d OpenCV
        |
        -sudo apt install zip cmake "and really a bunch of libs. located at https://docs.opencv.org/4.3.0/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html"
            | 
            - unzip opencv.zip
                |
                - mkdir build && cd build
                    |
                    - cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -DWITH_TBB=ON
                            -DBUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -DWITH_V4L=ON
                            -DINSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -DINSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON
                            -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -DWITH_QT=OFF -DWITH_OPENGL=ON ../
```

If you are on the Debian distro/server and you have under two to four cores, it will take an extra long time or you can port it to your Linux SBC via your favorite text editor or IDE.

---

Then once you use the `cmake` command, use `make` in the same "build" dir, and then ultimately use this command to install it, e.g. `sudo make install`.

That last command will install it in the correct locations.

Comment: One issue I have come across is with "make" in this reference. The "make" command stops at 71% with my debian distro/server for now. I will update everyone soon.